# Не корректная анимация появления div

Tags: css, reactjs

Есть контейнер содержимого в галерее, у него стоят display:flex и justify-content: center, так же у каждого элемента галереи есть эффект появления и исчезновения. В ряду галереи всегда идут 3 фотографии, потом следующий ряд, вот как раз случай, когда в последнем ряду меньше 3х фото и волнует меня. Содержимое в последнем ряду появляется сначала как-будто justify-content: flex-start, т.е. слева, когда анимация кончается элементы только тогда центруются. Вот собственно сама [галерея](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-merkle-6tgvn). И я не знаю в css ли проблема или в странно работающем react-transition-group. Еще я заметил, что центровка происходить только тогда, когда из DOM пропадают исчезнувшие элементы, но причинно-следственную связь понять не могу.

Comment: Как только элемент удаляется из DOM дерева он освобождает место и уже потом происходит центровка. У вас элементы по 30% шириной и пока элемент не удалился из DOM остальные просто не могут быть отцентрированы, т.к. место занято.

Comment: Есть идеи как победить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flex тут работает корректно. Просто при выборе группы картинок новые элементы добавляются мгновенно и сразу начинают занимать по 30% ширины блока, а старые удаляются только после завершения анимации, до завершения которой тоже занимают 30% от ширины.Тут либо смириться, либо удалять элементы мгновенно без анимации. Если подходит то в стилях добавьте вот это:

```
.gallery-image.photo-exit-active {
  display: none; // Добавляем 
}
```